# Hadoop NFS unable to start the Hadoop NFS gateway

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs

I am trying to install the NFS gateway on a Hadoop cluster.
Unfortunately I am not able to start the nfs gateway with the following Error.

I have also tried to add more debugging info by modifying the log4j file to include "Debug" info.  the Log4j file does not seem to be affecting the output.  So I also need to know how to increase the logging level.

```
    ************************************************************/
14/05/22 10:59:43 INFO nfs3.Nfs3Base: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value already present: sshd
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractBiMap.putInBothMaps(AbstractBiMap.java:112)
       at com.google.common.collect.AbstractBiMap.put(AbstractBiMap.java:96)
        at com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.put(HashBiMap.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.nfs.nfs3.IdUserGroup.updateMapInternal(IdUserGroup.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.nfs.nfs3.IdUserGroup.updateMaps(IdUserGroup.java:110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.nfs.nfs3.IdUserGroup.<init>(IdUserGroup.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3.<init>(RpcProgramNfs3.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3.<init>(RpcProgramNfs3.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.Nfs3.<init>(Nfs3.java:41)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.Nfs3.main(Nfs3.java:52)
14/05/22 10:59:45 INFO nfs3.Nfs3Base: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down Nfs3 at
************************************************************/
```

I suspected it is related to the following Issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-5587, however I do not understand from this issue what action I need to take.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the following Ticket, with workaround below:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-5587

Issue in my case was that sshd, and some other users existed in both the ldap and local box, but the UIDs did not match.

> NFS gateway can't start with duplicate name or id on the host system.
>   This is because HDFS (non-kerberos cluster) uses name as the only way
>   to identify a user or group. The host system with duplicated
>   user/group name or id might work fine most of the time by itself.
>   However when NFS gateway talks to HDFS, HDFS accepts only user and
>   group name. Therefore, same name means the same user or same group. To
>   find the duplicated names/ids, one can do:  and  on Linux systms,  and  on MacOS.